# "if statement filter for Perl"

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl to search a large file for specific Lat/Long data.
but I only want the Lat/Long data that belongs to the data that contains "GT017   " just before it

I've successfully grabbed the following data types
Call sign
Lat
Long
timestamp

But , I can not seem to limit the data acquired to only the Lat/Long/Timestamp that is tied to the Call sign GT017

I've tried if statements and sub routines but neither seem to allow me to only print the Lat/Long/timestamp that is specifically tied to the Call sign GT017

```
use strict;

#search for headers
my $find1= "GT017   ";
my $find2 = "timeStamp";
my $find3 = "latDD";
my $find4= "lonDD";

#above provides in response to my $find

#"callsign":"GT017   "
#"latDD":33.733200,
#"lonDD":-84.475667,
#"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:46:57.8Z",


open (NEW1, ">", "new1.txt" ) or die "could not open:$!";
open (FILE, "<", "test revab.txt") or die "could not open:$!";
while (<FILE>) {

#I want only a specific callsign's lat/long/timestamp printed

if ($find1 =~ /GT017/) {

print NEW1 if (/$find1/);
print NEW1 if (/$find2/);
print NEW1 if (/$find3/);
print NEW1 if (/$find4/);

}

}
close (FILE);
close (NEW1);
```

I get a large file with every Lat/Long/timestamp from the original file.

```
"latDD":33.733200,
"lonDD":-84.474266,
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:46:58.22Z",
"latDD":33.733200,
"lonDD":-84.474266,
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:46:58.8Z",
"latDD":33.708528,
"lonDD":-84.388506,
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:46:58.33Z",
```

The below is what I want for each occurrence of "callsign":"GT017   ",

```
"callsign":"GT017   ",
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:50.0Z",
"latDD":33.781071,
"lonDD":-84.401736,
```

Comment: Why not just print 3 lines after you find the callsign?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
my $find = '"callsign":"GT017   "';
while (<FILE>) {
    if (/\Q$find\E/) {
        print NEW1 $_;
        for (1..3) {
            print NEW1 scalar <FILE>;
        }
    }
}
```

this will print the line with callsign and the following 3 lines.

Comment: Thank you!!! your recommendation certainly works but I will have to pull in the file pre-filtered... the original data looks like:     "icaoAddress":"ACD0CA",
  "trafficSource":0,
  "latDD":33.733200,     *want this
  "lonDD":-84.475667,    * want this
  "altitudeMM":2994660,
  "headingDE2":9066,
  "horVelocityCMS":13221,
  "verVelocityCMS":-812,
  "squawk":6202,
  "altitudeType":0,
  "callsign":"GT017 ",      **search on this
  "emitterType":3,
  "sequenceNumber":10794,
  "pingStationGuid":"754104714b1002aa",
  "utcSync":1,
  "timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:46:57.8Z",    **want this

Comment: You are welcome! What do you mean by *"..pull in file pre-filtered.."* and what is meant by *".. want this"* and *"..search on this"*?

Comment: Hakon; first thank you again for the code. initially it took 2 steps to get the code to work the way I wanted..step 1....was my code that filtered the data down to essential elements... step 2...your code filtered the remaining data and put it in the needed desired format....I ended up putting your code in my initial script at the bottom and it now works as expected in one step....sincerely....THANK YOU